# 8-connectivity areas of each edge

Tags: matlab

i extracted edges of palmprint using canny edge detection algorithm, now want to extract principal lines of palm in this for that i want for 8-connectivity areas of each edge.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

To get 8-connected groups of pixels, you can use [BWCONNCOMP](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/bwconncomp.html). The connectivity is 8 by default.